# Finding the smallest Element in a Matrix [[Int]]

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell

I need to find the smallest element in a matrix.
I have a solution, but it is not perfect.

```
type Matrix = [[Int]]
matMin :: Matrix -> Int
matMin [] = 99999999999
matMin (xs:xss) = minimum xs `min` matMin xss
```

Can anyone give me a hint for a better solution?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest thing I can think of is just `matMin = minimum . concat`

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at `map` function. The minimum of a matrix is the minimum among the minimums from each line:

```
Prelude> :t minimum . map minimum
minimum . map minimum :: Ord c => [[c]] -> c
```

Answer (score 4):

A slightly tweaked version of your code, which avoids using a hardcoded value:

```
type Matrix = [[Int]]
matMin :: Matrix -> Int
matMin [] = error "min is undefined for 0x0 matrix"
matMin [xs] = minimum xs
matMin (xs:xss) = minimum xs `min` matMin xss
```

Or sticking with your approach, you could use `maxBound` instead (since `Int` is `Bounded`).

```
matMin :: Matrix -> Int
matMin [] = maxBound
matMin (xs:xss) = minimum xs `min` matMin xss
```

This, in fact, looks like a fold.

```
matMin = foldl' (acc x -> minimum x `min` acc) maxBound
```

Or if you want to get a little pointless

```
matMin = foldl' (flip (min . minimum)) maxBound
-- or if you don't like the flip
matMin = foldr (min . minimum) maxBound
```

Notice this pattern will work for any matrix "fold".

```
matFoldr :: (b -> c -> c) -- how to merge the accumulator with the result of mergeCells
         -> ([a] -> b)    -- how to merge a row of cells
         -> c             -- a starting accumulator value
         -> [[a]]         -- the matrix to fold over
         -> c
matFoldr mergeRows mergeCells start = foldr (mergeRows . mergeCells) start

matMin = matFoldr min minimum maxBound
matMax = matFoldr max maximum minBound
matSum = matFoldr (+) sum 0
matProduct = matFoldr (*) product 1
```

If we really really want to, we can even make it so you don't have to specify which list operation to use.

```
matEasyFold mergeRows start = matFoldr mergeRows mergeCells start
  where mergeCells = foldr mergeRows start

matMin = matEasyFold min maxBound
matSum = matEasyFold (+) 0
-- etc
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much :-p i solved much easier but it is very similar to the answer from Mihai

```
    matMin :: Matrix -> Int
    matMin xss = minimum(map minimum xss)
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, it's the same, except Mihai expressed it in [pointfree form](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree)